# Like/unlike transactions in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build a social app with Firebase. So, basically I have a `Post` class which is similar to what is given in the Firebase [docs/guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data)

```
public class Post {

        String uid;
        String timeStamp;
        String author;
        String body;
        int starCount = 0;
        Map<String, Boolean> stars = new HashMap<>();

        public Post() {
            // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
        }

        public Post(String uid, String author, String body, String timeStamp) {
            this.uid = uid;
            this.author = author;
            this.body = body;
            this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        }

        @Exclude
        public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            result.put("uid", uid);
            result.put("author", author);
            result.put("body", body);
            result.put("starCount", starCount);
            result.put("stars", stars);
            result.put("time", timeStamp);
            return result;
}

}
```

I'm using the same `writeNewPost()` method to save a new post, but since the `stars` hashmap is empty initially , the stars child is never created as a child node in the "posts" node.

Later when I try to use `postRef.getValue(Post.class)` or `postRef.setValue(Post.class)`, I get an error telling me no serializable data available.
I tried the obvious workaround and tried to do this which works totally fine -

```
           //this didn't work
           //Post post = postSnapShot.getValue(Post.class);

           Post post = new Post();

           post.uid = postSnapShot.child("uid").getValue(String.class);
           post.body = postSnapShot.child("body").getValue(String.class);
           post.starCount = postSnapShot.child("starCount").getValue(Integer.class);
           post.timeStamp = postSnapShot.child("time").getValue(String.class);
           post.author = postSnapShot.child("author").getValue(String.class);
```

But when I try to implement the like/unlike functionality, as mentioned again in the Firebase docs it's like this

```
    public boolean likeOrUnlikePost(String postId, final String uid) {

    DatabaseReference postRef = databaseReference.child(Constants.POSTS).child(postId);

    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            //Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            // above line didn't work again, so used the same workaround
            Post post = new Post();
            post.uid = mutableData.child("uid").getValue(String.class);
            post.body = mutableData.child("body").getValue(String.class);
            post.starCount = mutableData.child("starCount").getValue(Integer.class);
            post.timeStamp = mutableData.child("time").getValue(String.class);
            post.author = mutableData.child("author").getValue(String.class);
            post.stars = mutableData.child("stars").getValue(Map.class);
            if (post == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (post.stars.containsKey(uid)) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                post.starCount = post.starCount - 1;
                post.stars.remove(uid);
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                post.starCount = post.starCount + 1;
                post.stars.put(uid, true);
            }

            // below line didn't work as well
            // mutableData.setValue(post);


            //so I tried this which doesn't work as I assumed it to work.
            mutableData.child("starCount").setValue(post.starCount);
            mutableData.child("stars").setValue(post.stars);

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

So, I'm stuck with `mutableData.setValue()` which didn't work.
How do I solve this?

Edit:

Stacktraces of the error on the line

```
    Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
```

> postTransaction:onComplete:DatabaseError: User code called from the Firebase Database runloop threw an exception:
>                                                                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.dark.confess.Post
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy$zza.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.MutableData.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.dark.confess.FireBaseHelper$5.doTransaction(FireBaseHelper.java:120)
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajb.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$4.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: "get an error telling me no serializable data available" that sounds unexpected. Can you share the exact error message and a stack trace (pointing out the relevant line numbers in your code)? It would also help if you reduce the code to the minimum that is required to reproduce the issue. E.g., I doubt whether body, timestamp and author have anything to do with the error. Remove them from your code, see if you still have the problem and if you do, update the code in your question. Having less (but still complete) code makes it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No properties to serialize` in the `DataSnapshot.getValue()` method means you are missing the getter for the `Post` class' fields

```
public class Post {
    private String uid;
    private String timeStamp;
    private String author;
    private String body;
    private int starCount;
    private Map<String, Boolean> stars;

    public Post() {
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public int getStarCount() {
        return starCount;
    }

    public Map<String, Boolean> getStars() {
        return stars;
    }
}
```